# Samsun 840 SSD - errors using gdisk

Tags: ssd

I have an older Samsung 840 SSD which I have connected with a USB-C to SATA III cable to my (2018) MacBook Pro. In Terminal, I've tried erasing it and always get an error that it's unmounted, so I try to unmount it and it's busy. I used to use it for a backup disk but I erased and reformatted it for Windows (ExFAT) because I was going to put it in a friend’s laptop as an upgrade.  Then the friend moved away after I had reformatted it back and forth from exFAT to Fat32 to JHFS+ so many times - can't even remember.  Now it only shows up in Terminal after a while (~1 hour), listed as single volume with no name or type. There's no data on it - I just want to be able to create a partition and load macOS on it again.

I just installed gdisk and here's what it says:

```
Warning! Read error 16; strange behavior now likely!

Warning! Read error 16; strange behavior now likely!

Partition table scan:

MBR: not present
BSD: not present
APM: not present
GPT: not present

Creating new GPT entries in memory.

Command (? for help): p

Disk /dev/disk2: 976773168 sectors, 465.8 GiB
Sector size (logical): 512 bytes
Disk identifier (GUID): 306AFDDD-FE4D-4DAD-8F2A-C955BCBDD664
Partition table holds up to 128 entries
Main partition table begins at sector 2 and ends at sector 33
First usable sector is 34, last usable sector is 976773134
Partitions will be aligned on 2048-sector boundaries
Total free space is 976773101 sectors (465.8 GiB)

Number  Start (sector)    End (sector)  Size       Code  Name
[blank]

Command (? for help): o

Partition GUID code: 48465300-0000-11AA-AA11-00306543ECAC (Apple HFS/HFS+)
Partition unique GUID: 047050C3-8055-4BE9-8D2C-8D9960335A55
First sector: 2048 (at 1024.0 KiB)
Last sector: 976773134 (at 465.8 GiB)
Partition size: 976771087 sectors (465.8 GiB)
Attribute flags: 0000000000000000
Partition name: 'Apple HFS/HFS+'

Command (? for help): v

No problems found. 2014 free sectors (1007.0 KiB) available in 1
segments, the largest of which is 2014 (1007.0 KiB) in size.

Command (? for help): w

Final checks complete. About to write GPT data. THIS WILL OVERWRITE EXISTING
PARTITIONS!!

Do you want to proceed? (Y/N): y

OK; writing new GUID partition table (GPT) to /dev/disk2.
Warning: Devices opened with shared lock will not have their
partition table automatically reloaded!
Unable to open device '/dev/disk2' for writing! Errno is 2! Aborting write!
```

What should I do?  I'm completely ignorant and have no idea whether the drive is salvageable or if I should put in the trash and move on.  Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: A couple things: the SATA to USB-C "cable" is actually more of a HBA or interface translator. You should definitely consider it to be on your suspect list. And I vaguely remember a warning about `gdisk`, something along the lines of use `gpt` or `fdisk`, but have you tried using `diskutil` instead? I think that's what's most likely to work on your Mac.

Comment: I agree with @kumowoon1025 on the viability of the USB-C to SATA adapter.  However, out of curiosity, why are you using `gdisk` and not the built in `gpt` command

Comment: @kumowoon I have an old Mac Mini which I took apart and plugged this drive in as the secondary drive (the primary drive has macOS on it).  I can't remember what happened but it didn't work - it either wouldn't boot at all or it never recognized the drive.  I think it wouldn't boot.  So I used a USB-A to SATA cable to connect to the Mac Mini (different one than I'm using in my MacBook Pro) and still had the same issues.  I've even created a bootable USB with Gparted on it and tried that but it doesn't see the drive.

Comment: Using gdisk has gotten me further than any diskutil commands, all of which end up with the 69888 error (couldn't unmount disk) so I force unmount it, try eraseDisk again and get the69877 error (couldn't open device).  I don't know about the built-in got.  I just need someone to help me determine (through explicit directions, if possible) if it's trash or recoverable.

Comment: I was referring to `gpt` instead.  But, one thing you should try is zeroing out the disk.

Comment: @Allan Yes, I made a typo; meant gpt.  At one point I tried writing zeroes to the disk and got an error that it couldn't write to some portion of the disk. I have to look that command up again and try once more.

Comment: Though it's not very helpful in this case, you can sometimes get some more info on a Cocoa error code by querying it using `launchctl error <error-code>` (both show as `(operating system/?) unknown subsystem error`). The older Samsung in-house NAND controller chips had issues where with use, eventually data access would slow to a crawl, and firmware updates were released that partially addressed the issue - in some cases the flash was literally too "trashed" to fix as you say. Do you know which version of the firmware the controller is running? `EXT0BB6Q` seems to be the fixed version.

Answer (score 1):

Before you toss the disk I suggest you connect it to you Mac and try running Disk Utility app. It's usually located in the Application/Utilities folder. Start this app and see if your disk shows up, Disk Utility has an option to erase the disk. You can erase the disk and then create a partition formatted to whatever format you want. After that, I'd run First Aid on the disk to see if there are any problems. Disk Utility will fix most problems it encounters. Then disk should be ready to use on your mac.

Comment: I did try many times.  It takes hours before I get the box asking if I want to initialize the unknown disk, which if I do, finally shows up in the Disk Utility app.  It shows without any volumes.  I ran First Aid on it and it took 2 seconds, saying nothing was wrong.  Then when I erase it, it runs and runs and gives the 69888 error.  So I resorted to using commands in Terminal where it at least shows up within an hour after plugging in.